# Is it possible to print from within Chrome Package Apps?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is it possible to print from within Chrome Package Apps?

I'm looking for a solution where the user can print and it will automatically print to their default printer with prompting with the print dialogue.

I did quite a bit of research on this topic and wasn't able to find a definite answers or the answers is a bit old. If possible could possible provide a small snippet on how you can go about accomplishing it.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: The window.open() solution isn't going to really work in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `window.print();`, it will show the print dialog.